# Show that $ \mathbb P(X \in U)=\sup\limits \left \{\mathbb P(X \in K): K \subseteq U \text { is compact} \right \}.$

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

> Show that for any real random variable $X$ and any proper open subset $U$ of $\mathbb{R}$, we have $$\mathbb P(X \in U)=\sup\limits \left \{\mathbb P(X \in K): K \subseteq U \text { is compact} \right \}.$$

**My Attempt** $:$  Let $U \subseteq \mathbb R$ be open. Let $$\alpha : = \sup\limits \left \{\mathbb P (X \in K)\ :\ K \subseteq U\  \text {compact} \right \}.$$
For each $n \geq 1,$ consider the set $$K_n : = \left \{x \in U\ :\ d \left (x, U^c \right ) \geq n\ \text {and}\ \left \lvert x \right \rvert \leq n \right \}.$$
Then each $K_n$ is compact since the function $f : x \mapsto d \left (x, U^c \right )$ is
continuous and $$K_n = f^{-1} \left ( [n, \infty) \right ) \cap [-n,n].$$
Thus each $K_n,$ being the intersection of a closed set and a compact set
(in the Hausdorff space $\mathbb R),$ is compact.
Now for each $x \in U,$ there exists
$m_1 \in \mathbb N$ such that $\left \lvert x \right \rvert \leq m_1.$ Since $U^c$ is closed it follows that $d \left (x, U^c \right ) > 0$
and hence by Archimedean property there exists $m_2 \in \mathbb N$ such that
$d \left (x, U^c \right ) \geq \frac {1} {m_2}.$ Let $m_3 : = \max\limits \left \{m_1, m_2 \right \}.$ Then $x \in K_{m_3} \subseteq \bigcup\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} K_n.$ Since
$K_n \subseteq U$ for each $n \geq 1,$ it follows that $$U = \bigcup\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} K_n.$$
Since finite union of compact sets is compact, replacing $K_n$ by
$K_n^{\prime} : = \bigcup\limits_{j=1}^{n} K_j \subseteq U,$ it follows that $U$ can be written as a countable
increasing union of compact sets $K_n^{\prime}$ contained in $U.$ Then by the continuity of the
probability measure from below it follows that $$\mathbb P (X \in U) = \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \mathbb P \left (X \in K_n^{\prime} \right).$$
Hence $\alpha \geq \mathbb P (X \in U).$ But since $\mathbb P (X \in K) \leq \mathbb P (X \in U),$ for each
compact set $K \subseteq U,$ we also have $\alpha \leq \mathbb P (X \in U).$ Thus $\alpha = \mathbb P (X \in U),$
as required. $\square$

Is it fine what I did? Thanks for reading.